# SharePoint Visual WP ASP.net Update Panel - After exporting GridView to Excel events stop, nothing works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, updatepanel, export-to-excel

ASP.net SharePoint Visual Web Part with Update Panel.
GridView is exported on click of a button and **I get a prompt to save file**.
Exporting works
After that the page is no longer responsive. Buttons do not work as if events have stopped firing.
**ASCX Code:**

```
         <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
         <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
      <%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
     <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
     <%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
       <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/itportal/gridStyle.css" />
       <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/itportal/ITPortal.css" />
      <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IscarITTasksListUserControl.ascx.vb"
Inherits="ITPORTAL.IscarITTasksListUserControl" %>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplSearchParams" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="TRUE">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcelExport" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divSearchResults" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExcelExport" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="ExportToExcel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gridResults" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="true" GridLines="None" PageSize="25"
                ShowFooter="false" Width="100%">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderText="Id"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="item" ItemStyle-Width="20" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderText="Option" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" SortExpression="ModuleName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskDesc" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderText="Task Description" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" ItemStyle-Width="50%"
                        SortExpression="TaskDesc" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ResponsibleName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderText="Responsible" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" SortExpression="ResponsibleName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OpenUserName" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderText="Open" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" SortExpression="OpenUserName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OpenDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Open Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" SortExpression="OpenDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader"
                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Update Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" SortExpression="UpdateDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusNameEng" HeaderStyle-CssClass="itemHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                        HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="item" SortExpression="StatusNameEng" />
                </Columns>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingRow" />
                <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" ForeColor="Black" />
                <PagerSettings FirstPageImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/ITPORTAL/Grid/first.gif" LastPageImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/ITPORTAL/Grid/last.gif"
                    Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/ITPORTAL/Grid/next.gif"
                    PreviousPageImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/ITPORTAL/Grid/prev.gif" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
            </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    Protected Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnExcelExport.Click
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TaskListExport.xls")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Using sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        'To Export all pages
        gridResults.AllowPaging = False
        gridResults.AllowSorting = False
        gridResults.DataSource = dtResults.DefaultView
        gridResults.DataBind()

        gridResults.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White
        For Each cell As TableCell In gridResults.HeaderRow.Cells
            cell.BackColor = gridResults.HeaderStyle.BackColor
        Next
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gridResults.Rows
            row.BackColor = Color.White
            For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    cell.BackColor = gridResults.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
                Else
                    cell.BackColor = gridResults.RowStyle.BackColor
                End If
                cell.CssClass = "textmode"
            Next
        Next

        Dim frm As New HtmlForm()
        gridResults.Parent.Controls.Add(frm)
        frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
        frm.Controls.Add(gridResults)
        frm.RenderControl(hw)

       'style to format numbers to string
        Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
    End Using
    gridResults.AllowPaging = True
    gridResults.AllowSorting = True
    'gridResults.DataSource = dtResults.DefaultView
    'gridResults.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()` don't you think that would end the response? Are you familiar with how HTTP works? Once the response is over, there's not really much to do. If you wanted to continue interacting with the page, you'll need to do so in a separate request/response cycle (perform the download in a new tab/window)

Comment: @mason In that case, how do I instruct it to open in a new tab?

Comment: Well first off, I'd ditch the jerry rigged export junk you have there. You're not generating a real Excel file. You've got HTML masquerading as a XLS file. Use a library capable of generating a real XLS or XLSX file. Then put the logic for that into a separate handler (such as an ASHX) or use an MVC controller. Then put a hyperlink from your page to the handler or controller's action method and that will open it in a new tab for download (you won't actually see the tab, but it won't interfere with your page). I suggest you look into EPPlus, NPOI. ClosedXML, or Office XML SDK.

Comment: @mason I am hosted in SharePoint. This is a visual webpart as Control. So, in case I do want to keep this method, how do I just open it in a new tab?

Comment: Sorry, not going to help someone if they continue generating invalid files. That's just cruel to your users.

Comment: @mason Are you serious? The file is opening just fine. It does not have formatting like the gridView but I'll fix that later. What I need right now is for the page to continue to be responsive.

Comment: I'm quite serious - it's your duty as a developer to not generate invalid files. It just makes everyone's life hell when you do that. It's not hard to do the right thing. I've given you enough information to do it the wrong way if you wanted to.

Comment: @mason You're being condescending and that's plain wrong. I did not ask for help on this board to be patronized. I explained my limitations and I don't feel like excuses on my part are warranted in order to get some help. If you want to help, it shouldn't be on your terms. You're giving ultimatums. It's as if you're saying that if I'm not on your level, I shouldn't be coding. Or If I cannot implement your way because of limitations, then I'm not entitled to implement a solution at all. Read your first response and get the feel of how it sounds. I never encountered someone like you.

Comment: My "ultimatum" is aimed at making you a better developer and giving your users a better experience. You shouldn't be coding bad practices. I think you are fully capable of doing the right thing. Your limitations here are self imposed - have you investigating using any of the libraries I suggested? I've also given you enough info to do it your way if you wanted - surely you can create another page that allows you to download a file and link to it?

Comment: @mason Check this out: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx Try the demo and you'll see that his page is working fine after clicking the button and getting the file. My problem is not that. In SharePoint, you are hosted as a control that inherits from parent and there's also a master page. This guy's standalone solution works fine in a "regular" asp page. But not in Sharepoint. If I knew how to just pass the download to a new tab without killing response on my page, I'd do it and be done with it.

Comment: Create a new page that contains the GridView markup and that can generate the Excel file. Then create a hyperlink to that page from the page you want to initiate the download, or use JavaScript to open that page in new tab/window (there are plenty of examples online for how to do that).

Comment: @mason If I create a sharepoint aspx page and implement the file creation and download there, I would need to pass the datatable to that page as object. The search results can be huge. I mean HUGE. So, passing such an object to another page IS bad practice, correct?

Comment: You have several options. If the search itself doesn't take a long time to perform, you could pass the search terms via query string, your download page would then rerun the search with the same settings. Or if they do take a long time, you can store the results somewhere (Session or database etc) and just pass a reference to the key used to retrieve the search results.

Comment: @mason nevermind... found a simple solution. posting it as "Answer your Question"

Answer (score -1):

**Solved** 
Added OnClientClick to the button, like this:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExcelExport" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="ExportToExcel" OnClientClick="window.setTimeout(function() { _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; }, 10);" />
```